# Can DNS TXT record broke website?

Tags: domain-name-system, redirect, website, txt-record

I had job to verify website to Facebook with dns records. So I did it and now website shows hosting provider template and redirect to his website.

I had add something like this:

| NAME | FILE | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| example.com | TXT | "facebook-domain-verification=xyz" |

Privesly hosting settings send error when I tried set NAME to @ or leave blank so I set example.com. Now I know that I should add period after com like this:
"example.com."

Can this be a problem to access website? I deleted this record and it's been two hours after that. Still nothing changed. Should I wait more for propagation? I checked that,  all servers don't show Facebook txt over example.com .

Comment: A `TXT` record doesn't override existing `A` records, but your hosting company may have a web management solution that does. As it's, therefore, an issue with web hosting control panels, I'm voting to close this as off-topic.

Comment: I've faced this issue with cloudflare - it looks like adding TXT record for subdomain prevented wildcard A/AAAA record from covering this subdomain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting a TXT record should not interfere with the reachability of a website, that relies on A and AAAA records.

You can check DNS propagation with several tools, like https://www.whatsmydns.net for example.

Anyway, if you are using your hosting provider's web panel to configure DNS, the dot after example.com could be optional.
I would check example.com A record with the tool i suggested.

Comment: DNS doesn't propagate; it's cached. All the checks can and should be performed by requesting the records directly from the authoritative name servers. No need to wait.

Comment: That was good answer. When i tried to add record i change to manual configuration but i didn't notice that hosting is from another provider. So i changed Domain DNS. NS and A was set to locally server ns.example.com and should be ns.another.com (was before i changed to manual). Thanks for  help.